# Google Developer API service account authentication requests User Account

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, access-token

I am trying to authenticate to Google API services from a web server to check Customer subscription statuses. I am using PHP on my server. I could figure out how to get the access token from the server with the service account I have generated on the API console.

It works fine, but just after it pops up an authentication screen and once I log in with my user account. I was reading the documentation and it should work without asking me to log in, but I cannot figure out what is the problem.

My code is like this

```
$clientID="{my service account email address}.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$clientSecret="{my service account secret code}"; //Actually this is not used by the call      
$scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher";

$ch = curl_init();

$input_fields = 
    '&client_id='.$clientID.
    '&response_type=code'.
    '&type=service_account'.
    '&scope='. $scope .
    '&redirect_uri={my Redirect URI, set on the API Console}';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $input_fields);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Once this code is running, the authentication screen comes up, I need to grant access for website to access the API on behalf of my user account. After that I get the access token and the scope in a json using the Redirect URI page.

How can I avoid to be asked for my user account and just get the access token automatically?

Thanks for helping me out here.

Comment: Thats not service account authorization code thats standard OAuth2.  Oauth2 is going to request access of the user.   [service-account#httprest](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest)  if you get service account authorization working with curl i would love to see it so please post the answer.

Comment: Not exactly. It is application authentication, but you are right, that on behalf of the user, whose account will be used to access the API. What I could figure out that I should create a JWT with my credentials, somehow, but still not clear how it is done and what needs to be provided in it.

Comment: The link I supplied is the only link that i know of, I will tell you that i have tried on and off for eight years and have yet to manually be able to authorize a service account.   I recommend switching to a programming language where Google has created a library for you, it will be easer.

Comment: Yes, there is a PHP API package, but even that is not exactly clear how to utilise. It should be fairly simple, as they provide eg. a setting JSON object for the service, but the explanation is so weak, or I am dumb, but I cannot figure it out how to do that. Actually what I need I would be able to do it with the authentication, but then I need to manually start the subscription validity checking. But I am lazy, so I would like to make it with a cron job. For that PHP library would be perfect as well. Do you a working example for this in PHP?

Comment: The thing is if you want to access private user data then you shouldn't be using a service account you would need delignated access to the users account.   Which Google api are you trying to access?

Comment: No, I do not want to access private user data. I offer subscriptions to users and want to check on my backend server if the subscription is still valid or not. I need this, because the offered subscription is working on the backend server so if the user cancels the subscription outside of the app, I should know this. I am planning to have this checked I need to use the scope in the code above. This is a Google Play Developer API itself. So I can used it with my credentials, but I would like to reach it with the service account to run the subscription checks periodically and cancel features.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232653/discussion-between-endre-olah-and-daimto).